# How to make the listview to show a specific item in the center?

Tags: delphi, listview

Is there a universal method of placing a specific item (e.g. 500th from 1000) of the listview right in its center? Now I am using this code:

```
lvData.Items[iIndex].MakeVisible(False);
```

It's simple but has one flaw - mostly the required item appears at the top or at the bottom of the listview. Yes I know, it's not a big deal to scroll it manually but the way I use it (selecting a point on the graph and viewing the values of the nearby points in the listview) makes this behavior a little uncomfortable.

Comment: Use `TListView.TopItem` to see if you want to scroll up or down. `TlistView.Scroll` to scroll a certain amount of pixels.

Comment: @LU It would have been a working method if this item had always appeared in the same position, but it does not, it can be shown anywhere.

Comment: @LU Sorry, the previous answer was to your unedited question

Comment: If you know which item is at the top, how much space each item takes, and the distance between the top item and the target item, then you have what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `DisplayRect` of an item to determine where it currently lives.
Given `ListView1` is the listview, `li` is the list item and `R` is a `TRect` variable

```
R := li.DisplayRect(drBounds);
ListView1.Scroll(0, R.Top - ListView1.ClientHeight div 2);
```

will scroll the item in the center, provided there are enough items.

Comment: You are a rock star developer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an idea. The `TopItem` gives the topmost item in view and `VisibleRowCount` gives how many visible rows there are. To make this complete, make a sanity check for the new index.

```
if (lvData.TopItem < iIndex) then
  adjustedIndex := iIndex-(lvData.VisibleRowCount div 2)   
else
  adjustedIndex := iIndex+(lvData.VisibleRowCount div 2);
// Check adjustedIndex
if (adjustedIndex < 0) then
  adjustedIndex := 0;
if (adjustedIndex >= lvData.Items.Count) then
  adjustedIndex := lvData.Items.Count-1;

lvData.Items[adjustedIndex].MakeVisible(false);
```